# Rider: How to change background color of the selected tab?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I use rider from JetBrains for my C# project, and the thing that annoys me is the color of the background of the active tab (see a screenshot).

[image: tab screenshot]

I would like to change it and set the color I want.

The options I found in settings didn't help me (Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Editor -> Tabs).

[image: settings]

The scheme changing didn't help also.

Did I miss something?

Comment: 1) Is that definitely a color for active tab? I mean -- if you change to another tab then that tab will be highlighted using that color? 2) Setting custom colors for "Tabs | Selected Tab" works for me (PhpStorm .. but it should work the same as they both on the same IDEA platform): https://postimg.cc/njJJkyyH 3) What custom plugins do you have installed? Maybe it's one of them? Try disabling all non-bundled plugins and restart IDE -- see if anything has changed.

Comment: @LazyOne You are right. I had a strange extension, which was the cause of the problem. I've disabled it, and now the tab color is ok. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share the name of that plugin, please? Would be helpful to know what to look in the future / maybe that plugin meant to do that..

Comment: Surprisingly its name is "Active Intellij Tab Highlighter" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in installed plug-in `Active Intellij Tab Highlighter`